# SQL command into linq expression entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework, linq

I have 2 tables: Oceny_przedmioty and Studenci. Studenci and Oceny_przedmioty are in connection  one - many (one student can have more than 1 grade). I need to make from this SQL :

```
SELECT Oprz_Ocena 
    FROM Oceny_przedmioty 
    UNION SELECT ST_Nr_indeksu 
          FROM Studenci 
          WHERE ST_Nr_indeksu = '11000'
```

linq expression what Visual Studio will understand. I work with entity framework.
I tried something like this

```
   var currentGrade= (from Oceny_przedmioty in dbContext.Oceny_przedmioty
                            select Oceny_przedmioty.ID_Studenta).Union
                             (from Studenci in dbContext.Studenci
                              select Studenci.ID_Studenta);
```

but it doesn't even recognizes Union (does not contain a definition for Union). Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Your code snippet looks fine.  Make sure you have `using System.Linq;` in order to use the .Union() function

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Comment: Hi! I'm using System.Linq,I have this issue: "'IQueryable<int?>' does not contain a definition for 'Union and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Union<int>(ParallelQuery<int>, IEnumerable<int>)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<int> ".

Comment: For one-to-many relations usually joins are used, not unions. What sense does it make to union students and grades? This would create a mix of student records and grade records. A join would create records of pairings of students with their corresponding grades.

Comment: Hi @OlivierJacot-Descombes, as you see in SQL query at the end is WHERE statement, which I have to put also in linq expression. I wanted to try something simple, and then complicate it with WHERE statement.

Comment: Looks like `Oceny_przedmioty.ID_Studenta` type is `int?` (nullable int) while `Studenci.ID_Studenta` just `int`. Parts of the `Union` has to have one and the same element type. Why don't you select the fields corresponding to your SQL query (which seem to be `string`s).

Comment: Replace `select Oceny_przedmioty.ID_Studenta` with `select Oceny_przedmioty.ID_Studenta.Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all for your response! The problem also was with query and this code resolved all my problems

```
var query1 = dbContext.Oceny_przedmioty    
           .Join(dbContext.Studenci,
              post => post.ID_Studenta,        
              meta => meta.ID_Studenta,  
              (post, meta) => new { meta.ST_Nr_indeksu, post.OPrz_Ocena })
            .Where(postAndMeta => postAndMeta.ST_Nr_indeksu == 11000);    

       dataGridView1.DataSource = query1.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

can you try like this. Include namespace `using System.Linq;` if not already done

```
var india = context.Orders.Where(o => o.ShipCountry == "India").Select(o => o);
var usa= context.Orders.Where(o => o.ShipCountry == "USA").Select(o => o);
var IndiaUnionusa = india.Union(usa);
```

for you code it will be like

```
 var quer1= (from Oceny_przedmioty in dbContext.Oceny_przedmioty
                            select Oceny_przedmioty.ID_Studenta);
 var query2 = (from Studenci in dbContext.Studenci
                              select Studenci.ID_Studenta);
  var currentGrade = query1.Union(query2);
```

---

seems like problem with int? nullable type

```
 var quer1= (from Oceny_przedmioty in dbContext.Oceny_przedmioty
                            select Oceny_przedmioty.ID_Studenta)
                            .ToList();
 var query2 = (from Studenci in dbContext.Studenci
                              select Studenci.ID_Studenta)
                             .ToList();
 var currentGrade = query1.Union(query2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, where is Union line I have this error: "IQueryable<int?>' does not contain a definition for 'Union and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Union<int>(ParallelQuery<int>, IEnumerable<int>)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<int>"

Comment: @AleksandraSkoczypiec - updated my answer can you please try that now